# How to associate .dll with the proper version of Dependency Walker?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, dll

There is a cool life-hack that I learned from my colleague: you associate .dll files with Dependency Walker, and now whenever you try to "run" a .dll file, it opens Dependency Walker for its analysis.

The problem is that there are two version of Dependency Walker: one 32-bit and another 64-bit. And it is recommended to use version of the same bitness for a .dll:

> Yes. Dependency Walker will work with any 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module. There are 32-bit and 64-bit versions Dependency Walker.  All versions are capable or opening 32-bit and 64-bit modules.  **However, there are major advantages to using the 32-bit Dependency Walker to process 32-bit modules and the 64-bit Dependency Walker to process 64-bit modules.**  This is especially true when running on a 64-bit version of Windows, which allows execution of both 32-bit and 64-bit programs.  The 32-bit subsystem on 64-bit Windows (known as "WOW64") has its own private registry, "AppPaths", "KnownDlls", system folders, and manifest processing.  Only the 32-bit version of Dependency Walker can access this 32-bit environment, which is needed to accurately process a 32-bit module.  Likewise, only the 64-bit version of Dependency Walker can fully access the 64-bit environment, so it should always be used for processing 64-bit modules.

Is there a way to associate 32-bit dlls with 32-bit version of Dependency Walker and 64-bit dlls with 64-bit version of Dependency Walker? I'm particularly interested in answer for Windows 7 or 10.

Comment: Most easiest way would be to someone to write a In-between program which you assign to open DLL files. Then that program should decide which Dependency walker to launch.

Comment: "Is there a way to associate 32-bit dlls with 32-bit version of Dependency Walker and 64-bit dlls with 64-bit version of Dependency Walker?" - A 64-bit process can only reference 64-bit dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a python-based tool for this purpose: https://github.com/mmatrosov/DllDispatcher

The tool is pretty straightforward. As it is mentioned in the corresponding readme, you associate .dll with `DllDispatcher.bat` file, which calls `DllDispatcher.py` file, which analyses the .dll content and determines whether the provided dll is 32-bit or 64-bit. Based on this, it then calls one of the two provided applications. Paths to the applications are simply hard-coded at the beginning of `DllDispatcher.py` file.

I found no easy way to determine whether a dll is 32-bit or 64-bit. `GetBinaryType` only works for .exe files. For a dll one should either actually load the library and then pass the handle to `IsWow64Process()`, or manually parse the header of the dll (it has PE file format). I chose the latter. It is less robust, but more fast. I think robustness is not a big issue, since it is unlikely for the PE format to change in the near future, and this solution does not have to be completely bullet-proof.